# How causal consistency is different to sequential consistency?

Tags: java, c, algorithm, concurrency, memory-model

I understand that in sequential consistency all processes have to be processed sequentially. For example:

```
Process 1     Process 2
x = 1         z = 5
y = 2         p = 3
```

So, we can get x=1, z=5, y=2, p=3 or z=5, p=3, x=1, y=2. But what matters is that p can only be executed once z is executed etc, correct?

What about causal consistency? I don't see any difference there. Any sketches, or code in JAVA or C would be great. Thank you.

Comment: The difference is explained here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_consistency.

Comment: Your understanding seems right, but your wording is slightly off so I'm not sure if you really understand. All processes don't **have** to be processed sequentially. All that has to happen is that the end result of be the same as if the operations were executed in *some* sequential order, and the operations of each individual process appear in the order that is specified by the code associated with each such process. There's a big difference. So yes, `p=3` can only can after `z = 5`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It's very difficult worded... An example would be great...

Comment: @evening By the way this question is probably better suited for the [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In *sequential consistency* all of the memory operations appear *to all nodes* to have appeared in some order.

So in your example processes 1, 2, *and 3* would all see the memory operations in the same order.  (There are 6 possible orders for the 4 operations, but all the processes would agree on what that order is.)

In *causal consistency* processes 1, 2 and 3 could all observe those writes to occur in different orders.  There are two rules:

1. Everyone agrees that process i's writes happened in the same order that process i did them.
2. If any process, i, does a read of a location `x` and gets a value that was written by a different process, j, then all the threads agree that process j's write to location x preceded process i's read of location x.

Since, in your original example there are no read operations then it is possible, for example, for process 1 to believe that the writes happened in the order `x=1, y=2, z=5, p=3` while process 2 believes that the writes happened in the order `z=5, p=3, x=1, y=2` and process 3 believes that they happened in order `z=5, x=1, p=3, y=2`.

The [paper that the Wikipedia page points to](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.50.3356) gives some examples that are more interesting (involve reads).

Causal memory by itself seems not very useful.  Later in the paper they show how to implement something kind of like a barrier with a causal memory (and a helper process), but mention that there doesn't seem to be any convenient way to implement a critical section.

So they end up doing what *weakly consistent* or *release consistent* memories do, and adding a synchronization primitive, which needs to be sequentially consistent.

Comment: Useful or not, some of the interest in causal consistency comes from a proof that asking for more than causal consistency sacrifices one or more of availability and performance in a distributed system - http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/princem/papers/cac-tr.pdf says - Specifically, in the asynchronous
model with omission-failures and unreliable networks, we show the following tight bound: No consistency
stronger than Real Time Causal Consistency (RTC) can be provided in an always-available,
one-way convergent system and RTC can be provided in an always-available, one-way convergent
system.

Comment: You're right.  I was forgetting about distributed systems.  My background (bigotry?) is in systems with only 100s of cores on the same mother board, where the assumption is that the system is working if and only if every part is working.  With truly distributed systems the tradeoffs are completely different.